# How do I prevent the removal of a slash from an input String?

Tags: java, escaping

The user inputs a String corresponding to a file path. However, since Java automatically removes a \, they have to put two \'s. How can I make them just input a String like C:\path\filename.txt without needing to worry about adding apostrophes or additional slashes or whatever?

```
public String getDescriptorPath(){
    return this.textField.getText();
}
```

Allow me to clarify: the user types into a TextField.

Let's say he types: "C:\Users\daniel.bak\Box Sync\Descriptor Analyzer\AnalyzeMe.xml"

That comes out as "C:Usersdaniel.bakBox SyncDescriptor AnalyzerAnalyzeMe.xml"

I am adding the extra slashes here because StackOverflow does the same thing.

Comment: java does not remove a '\'. You just need to add an extra '\' if you want to represent this char, since it is an escape char.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a little confused as to what you mean, when I take a JTextField and print it's contents it gives me the exact same as I see on screen.

Contents of JTextField: "C:\path\file.txt"
Terminal Output: "C:\path\file.txt"

This string then should be valid to make a File out of it, or however you want to process it.

Comment: The contents of the JTextField are only "C:\path\file.txt" if the user types in "C:\\path\\file.txt" though, right?

I had no idea it would be this frustrating trying to explain this problem.

Comment: Actually not, I tried that in windows and mac os x and it worked the way I explained it.

Comment: Yeah, I think this entire question was predicated on a mistake I made.

Answer (score 1):

If the path is inputed manually from keyboard (for example from `scanner.nextLine()`) or is read from a file the corresponding string contains the correct number of slashs.

For example if in a text file you have the following characters

```
C:\path\filename.txt
```

When in java you read the content of that file in a string the content is equivalent to the following string

```
"C:\\path\\filename.txt"
```

Comment: Allow me to clarify: the user types into a TextField.

Let's say he types: "C:\Users\daniel.bak\Box Sync\Descriptor Analyzer\AnalyzeMe.xml"

That comes out as "C:Usersdaniel.bakBox SyncDescriptor AnalyzerAnalyzeMe.xml"

I am adding the extra slashes here because StackOverflow does the same thing.

Comment: To be sure that the data are correct simple print the string. If you see two slashs it is incorrect. If you see one slash is correct.

Comment: When you take the text from the JTextField Java automatically stores the string with proper escaped '\'. Check the value of the String with the debugger if you want to be sure

Comment: I don't want it to escape the '\\'. The user will only be entering one slash and I want it not to escape.

Comment: If you read the data from the JTextField and you save the data in String and printing that string you see 1 slash all works fine. You don't need any additional code. This is only a test to show you that the data are correct!